# is there any lib is available for splitting xml file based on tags in spark?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I try to split the XML file in Spark Scala. I find the JAXB lib for splitting the XML data in Java but I couldn't find any lib for Spark Scala. Is there any lib is available?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) lib ?